# image with bootstrap, breaking column/div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, tinymce

I've built a CMS of sorts and I'm having some issues using TinyMCE and Bootstrap.

I have a page where a div is outlined, and if the user clicks in the div they can choose images from a modal. The image is inserted into a tinymce instance and when the user hits 'save' it's saved with html (from tinymce) into the database but it is also added into the div for the preview.

I need help finding a way to make sure that no matter how large the image is it stays contained in the bootstrap column.

The empty div:

[image]
and after adding a large image

[image]

Is there something I can use in the html here for bootstrap that will ensure, even if a huge image is put in tinyMce, that it won't break the div?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Template One</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    @import "style.css";
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .modal-lg {
      max-width: 80% !important;
    }
    
    .my-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
    .my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
      background-color: #929292;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .my-container>.middle {
      flex-grow: 1;
      padding: 30px;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .my-container>.middle>* {}
    
    #clock {
      /*background-color:#333;*/
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 40px;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    #clock span {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 40px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #date {
      margin-top: -10px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .buttonContainer {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="src/ytv.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid my-container">
    <div class="row middle">
      <div class="col-lg-6 leftFifty" id="leftFifty">
        <div class="leftContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; border: dotted 1px black;">
          <!-- This is the div that is clicked in to select an image -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 rightFifty" id="rightFifty">
        <div class="rightContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; border: dotted 1px black; ">
          <!-- This is the div that is clicked in to select an image -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the images is a img tag or a background-imges?

Comment: They have an image tag, because that's how TinyMCE saves them. But sometimes this will be text rather than an image so I can't explictly create an image tag, though I could say something like "IF img, then..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really all you have to do is set `width: 100%`; Height can be `auto` or completely omitted to preserve aspect ratio.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Template One</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    @import "style.css";
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .modal-lg {
      max-width: 80% !important;
    }
    
    .my-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
    .my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
      background-color: #929292;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .my-container>.middle {
      flex-grow: 1;
      padding: 30px;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .my-container>.middle>* {}
    
    #clock {
      /*background-color:#333;*/
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 40px;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    #clock span {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 40px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #date {
      margin-top: -10px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    .buttonContainer {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="src/ytv.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/master/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gijgo@1.9.6/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid my-container">
    <div class="row middle">
      <div class="col-lg-6 leftFifty" id="leftFifty">
        <div class="leftContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; border: dotted 1px black;">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x250" />
          <!-- This is the div that is clicked in to select an image -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 rightFifty" id="rightFifty">
        <div class="rightContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%; border: dotted 1px black; ">
          <!-- This is the div that is clicked in to select an image -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow that actually fixed that issue, but I put another image into the right div that was much taller and wider and it still breaks out of the height

Comment: So the left image was 1800x824 and it fits fine, the right div image that i tested was 1024 x 942 and it's width was contained but the bottom went out of the dotted line

Comment: COuld it be because I have rows above and below this .row-middle?

Comment: IN the fiddle, if I do 1024x942 it seems to fit

Comment: Try giving images a 
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%

Comment: @RobQuan I tried max-height and it worked in the fiddle but I may have found the issue: THe images once they go through TinyMCE have a paragraph tag. When I put a <p> tag around the image it breaks for a 1024x942 image

Comment: @RobQuan check this fiddle. this uses max-height and has a p tag around the image currently https://jsfiddle.net/vbuf0gwL/12/

Comment: Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3rwxgf0v/
Set the overflow on the parent p tag to auto